# Redirect to user's profile anytime possible. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am trying to make a link to user's profile! So I have this in User's controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    #defining the "@user" object for the form_for
    @user = User.new    
  end

  #defining a function for the "show" html file
  def show
    #get user id by URL address
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  #handling user login succes or failure
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save

        #using "flash" variable Ruby
        #flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!" <<< use this !!

        #render success page
        redirect_to @user
    else
        #render failure page (using error partial page)
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  #mine to show user profile
  def show_user

    render 'show'

  end
end
```

and in my routes.rb I got:

```
DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do

  get "intergration_test/authentication_pages"

  #Removed!
  #get "users/new"

  #ROOT page 
  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  #My routes
  match '/user_profile', to: 'users#show_user'

  #REST architecture for users
  resources :users

  #including the Sessions action
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  #Note the use of via: :delete for the signout route, which indicated that it should be invoked using an HTTP DELETE request
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

end
```

So why does

```
  #mine to show user profile
  def show_user

    render 'show'

  end
```

returns me the error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

it is like the user is null! I am already logged in! so I should have a user active.
even if I use `redirect_to @user` it does not work! help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the `show` template has access to 'user' via the `@user` instance variable. If so, then you need to set the instance variable:

```
def show_user
 @user = current_user // Or other method for getting the logged in user. 
 render 'show'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say that you are in index page , and you want to create a link to redirect to a user you can just use something like :

```
<%= link_to 'Show User', current_user %>
```

the user is the user object and from the default rest route it will take you to show action of the page, so no need to create an action in your controller 'show_user'

And can your provide the view of the controller and how you call the show_user action